# Attaching from inside of screen? in screen session

Tags: gnu-screen

I had a couple of session running on a screen session

```
There are screens on:
5073 (Attached)
1865 (Attached)
2 Sockets in /run/screen/S-user
```

I have tried to use 1865 by using

```
screen -x 1865
```

The screen has the following statement.
    Attaching from inside of screen?

How to see what is going on in screen 1865.

I have tried using

```
screen -r -d 1865
screen -D -r 1865
```

but the same thing appears.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following command to resume the attached session.

```
screen -S 1865
```

This resumed the screen session and I was able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
screen -X -S 1865 quit
```

This command can detach the screen from socket.

Comment: this command will kill the screen